# problem with asymptotic variance of the MLE

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance

Let $(X1....Xn)$ be i.i.d.random variables with p.d.f.
$$f(x) =\frac{1}{\theta} (1-x)^{\frac{1-\theta}{\theta}} $$  $0<x<1$   $\theta>0$

1. find MLE specifying asymptotic variance

I found $$\theta_{MLE} = -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n log(1-X_i)}{n}$$

Since the second derivative of the likelihood is negative in $\theta_{MLE}$ What I found is a max
Then to specify the asymptotic variance I should find the fisher information and the asymptotic variance is equal to the inverse of the fisher
I got for the second derivative $$\frac{d^2logL(\theta)}{d^2(\theta)} = \frac{n}{\theta^2}+2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n log(1-X_i)}{\theta^3}$$
To find the fisher information I should compute the expected value of the second derivative $$I_n = -E(\frac{d^2logL(\theta)}{d^2(\theta)})$$

I get stuck finding the expected value of  $\sum_{i=1}^n log(1-X_i)$ I could find $E(X)$ by doing the $\int_{0}^1 x*f(x)$ but how Can I find the expected value of $\sum_{i=1}^n log(1-X_i)$

help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have no doubt the mathematicians here will make short work of this problem. Having said that, this could be a good question for stats.stackexchange.com as well. Fun question it takes me back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y = -\log( 1 - X) $, then
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P(Y\le y)\\
 &= P(-\log(1-X)\le y)\\
 &= P( e^{-y} \le 1 - X )\\
& = P ( X < 1- e^{-y})\\
& = F_X(1-e^{-y}),
\end{align}
hence, using the fact that $f_Y(y) = \frac{\partial }{ \partial y} F_Y(y)$, we have
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X( 1- e^{-y}) e^y = \theta^{-1}e^{-y(1/\theta - 1)}e^y = \theta^{-1} e^{-y/\theta},
$$
where $ 0 < X < 1$ then $1 < 1 - X < 0$, hence $Y = - \ln ( 1- X) > 0$.
So, as you can see, $Y \sim Exp(1/\theta)$, hence $E[Y] = \theta$.

Comment: $-y\leq 1-X$ should be $e^{-y}\leq 1-X$

Comment: could you please explain how do you get
$$f_Y(y) = f_X( 1- e^{-y}) e^y = \theta^{-1}e^{-y(1/\theta - 1)}e^y = \theta^{-1} e^{-y/\theta}, y > 0$$                                                                                                                            Have you differentiated $F_x(1-e^{-y})$?

Comment: I've added some steps. Hope it clarifies the calculations.